# What I should do when using Gitflow Workflow and the master progress?

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

I've read about Gitflow Workflow [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) and they say to create a **develop** branch from **master** and a **feature** branch from **develop**. So I forked a repo and I created a branch **develop** having the latest commit on **master** (C1) as parent, then I created two **features** branches from **develop** branch where I'm working. Now **master** has new commits but my **develop** branch and **features** branches are still based on the older commit(C1).

There is a way to integrate changes as **master** progress, like changing where is pointing the **develop** branch? Maybe using rebase but I don't know how to apply to my case. **develop** and **features** branches are local.

In few words how to work on a feature and constantly integrate the progress from master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep your branches in sync with `master` you basically will need to this:

First, change to master branch and get the changes:

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

Then change to your branch and put it in sync with `master`:

```
git checkout your-branch
git merge master
```

Depending on what you are working on it may create some conflicts while merging the ones you will have to solve.

In case you don't want to update first your local master branch you can update directly your local branch with the `<remote>/master` by doing this:

```
git checkout your-branch
git rebase origin/master
```

You could also push directly from your branch to master:

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

But will not play nice with the gitflow, better push to `develop`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. So `git checkout your-branch` and then `git rebase origin/master` what it does? Is basing `your-branch` on `origin/master`? I understand how rebase works and it creates new commits, is it adding the commit of `master progress` in `your-branch` and then re-apply my commits on top of it? I would like to avoid merge commits if possible

Comment: @Mattia `git rebase origin/master` will merge in the requested branch (`origin/master` in this case) and apply the commits that you have made locally to the top of the history without creating a merge commit (assuming there were no conflicts)